# Regular Expression misses matches in string

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures desired strings between strings
("f38 ","f38  ","f1 ", "..") and ("\par","\hich","{","}","","..") from a decompiled DOC file and append each match to an array to eventually be printed out into a new file.

I'm having an issue with catching certain strings between "f38 " and "\hich" (usually when the string spans multiple lines but there is at least 1 exception to this I've found in the example string snippet of the DOC file I'm using on regex101.com)

Here is the regular expression as I have it now

```
(?<=f38  |f38 | |f1 |\.\.)\w.+(?=\\par|\\cell |\\hich|{|}|\\|\.\.)
```

The troublesome matches come out including "\hich". Like "e\hich" and "d\hich" and I want to match "e" and "d" respectively in these examples not the \hich portion. I'm thinking the problem is with handling the newline/line-breaks somehow.

Here is a smaller snippet of the input string, I have bolded what is matched and bolded + capitalized the problematic match. From this I want the "e" not the \hich. Note that above there are 2 examples of things going right and "\hich" is not included in the match.

**l**\hich\af38\dbch\af31505\loch\f38 ..**ikely to involve asbestos exposure: removal, encapsulation, alteration, repair, maintenance, insulation, spill/emergency clean-up, transportation, disposal and storage of ACM. The general industry standards cover all other operations where exposure to asb**..\hich\af38\dbch\af31505\loch\f38 **E\HICH**\af38\dbch\af31505\loch\f38 **stos is possible**

Here is an example with a longer portion of the input string [at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qQtLs7/1)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the regex link, that contains a comprehensive input text, can you update your question with some "more-contained" smaller samples of what you need to match from that input text?

Comment: @lemon OK I edited the post to include a more encapsulated example. Does this help?

Comment: Sure it helped. Check n0rd's solution in the answers, as it seems to be solving your issue.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the part you want to match those single-character samples. `\w.+` requires *at least* two characters to match. So, for when you get "e\hich" that first backslash get matched to the dot in regex and lasts until the next backslash (which is one of the "terminators" listed in the positive lookahead portion of the regex).

You might want to use `*` instead of `+`.

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Thank you! I need more rep to upvote. I will revisit this post to do so once that is the case.

Comment: You can accept it as the solution